# If Statement if Row is not Outlined

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The below is used to control code depending on outline level of row.
It is working except for when there is no outline level.

Is it correct to use `OutlineLevel = 0` when no outlining? I cannot find any information on this.

```
If ActiveCell.Rows.OutlineLevel = 0 Then MsgBox "No group Selected", vbCritical, "Admin": Exit Sub
    
If ActiveCell.Rows.OutlineLevel = 2 Then MsgBox "Please Collapse group first", vbCritical, "Admin": Exit Sub
        
If ActiveCell.Rows.OutlineLevel = 1 Then
```

Comment: [**Level one** is the outermost summary level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.outlinelevel). Try `if ActiveCell.EntireRow.OutlineLevel=1 then ...`

Comment: Just wondering why Rows behaves differently to EntireRow here?

Comment: Entirerow is the whole sheet row, but row is a row inside the range (activecell in this case)

Comment: I will try to understand why this gives 2 different results! Thanks